# Kivy ListView won't update the item_strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Here is my .py file

```
import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty
import json

class LibraryMain(BoxLayout):

    search_input = ObjectProperty()
    search_results = ListProperty()

    def searched_location(self):
        print(self.search_results)
        newis = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
        self.search_results.extend(newis)
        print(self.search_results)
        print(f"""Searched for: {self.search_input} {self.search_results}""")


class LibraryApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LibraryApp().run()
```

and my .kv file

```
LibraryMain:

<LibraryMain>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    search_input: search_box.text
    search_results: search_results_list.item_strings
    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        TextInput:
            id: search_box
            size_hint_x: 50
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: root.searched_location()
        Button:
            text: "Search"
            size_hint_x: 25
            on_press: root.searched_location()
        Button:
            text: "Current Location"
            size_hint_x: 25
            on_press: root.searched_location()
    ListView:
        id: search_results_list
        item_strings: ['a']
```

The function assigns a new value to the ListProperty and this new value should get passed into search_results_list.item_strings to display in the ListView, but it doesn't and I haven't seen why.

[image: List item 'a' shows, but '1', '2', '3', '4' are missing]

Could someone please enlighten me on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following expression:

```
search_results: search_results_list.item_strings
```

You are doing a binding if it is set if `item_strings` is updated then `search_results` will be updated with those new values, but that does not imply that if `search_results` is modified `item_strings` will be notified and updated.

What you must do is the reverse as I show below:

***.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty


class LibraryMain(BoxLayout):
    search_input = ObjectProperty()
    search_results = ListProperty(['a'])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        BoxLayout.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    def searched_location(self):
        print(self.search_results)
        newis = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
        self.search_results.extend(newis)
        print(self.search_results)
        print(f"""Searched for: {self.search_input} {self.search_results}""")

class LibraryApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LibraryApp().run()
```

***.kv**

```
LibraryMain:

<LibraryMain>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    search_input: search_box.text
    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        TextInput:
            id: search_box
            size_hint_x: 50
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: root.searched_location()
        Button:
            text: "Search"
            size_hint_x: 25
            on_press: root.searched_location()
        Button:
            text: "Current Location"
            size_hint_x: 25
            on_press: root.searched_location()
    ListView:
        id: search_results_list
        item_strings: root.search_results  # <--
```

---

In conclusion the following expression:

```
obj_a:
    property_a : obj_b.property_b
```

Indicates that modifying the `property_b` of `obj_b` then `property_a` of `obj_a` will be updated but not vice versa.

```
obj_a.property_a <--- obj_b.property_b
```

Comment: Thanks for sorting me on this, I was close, but just didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

The ListView's *item_strings* is not updated because the following statement means ***search_results*** is assigned the ***values*** from ***search_results_list.item_strings***.

```
search_results: search_results_list.item_strings
```

The ***id() function*** will show that both variables (*search_results* and *listview's item_strings*) do not point to the same list object. Therefore, the *item_strings* is not updated when *search_results* is updated.

## Solution

### Python file

1. Change *search_results* from *ListProperty* to *ObjectProperty*
2. Replace *self.search_results* with *self.search_results.item_strings*
3. Replace *pass* with *def build(self): return LibraryMain()*

### kv file

1. Replace *search_results: search_results_list.item_strings* with *search_results: search_results_list*
2. There are two root widgets declared. Remove **LibraryMain:**

   LibraryMain:    # this is a root widget

   <LibraryMain>:    # this is a rule

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class LibraryMain(BoxLayout):

    search_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    search_results = ObjectProperty(None)

    def searched_location(self):
        print(self.search_results.item_strings)
        newis = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
        self.search_results.item_strings.extend(newis)
        print(self.search_results.item_strings)
        print(f"""Searched for: {self.search_input} {self.search_results.item_strings}""")


class LibraryApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return LibraryMain()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LibraryApp().run()
```

### kv file

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<LibraryMain>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    search_input: search_box.text
    search_results: search_results_list
    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        TextInput:
            id: search_box
            size_hint_x: 50
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: root.searched_location()
        Button:
            text: "Search"
            size_hint_x: 25
            on_press: root.searched_location()
        Button:
            text: "Current Location"
            size_hint_x: 25
            on_press: root.searched_location()
    ListView:
        id: search_results_list
        item_strings: ['a']
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - ListView's item_strings updated]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I didn't want to change from ListProperty.